# web2py: turning off internationalization of auth_event database table?

Tags: web2py

The 'description' field of my 'auth_event' table stores events in the language of the country of the visitor associated with a particular event. For example, if somebody from Greece logs in to my site, the description field will note the login in Greek. Is there a way to turn off internationalization for this table, so that all events are logged in English? Thanks.

Comment: The logging messages are stored in `auth.messages`, along with all of the other Auth messages. `auth.messages` is a `gluon.storage.Messages` object, which automatically translates each message upon retrieval. I'd say this behavior is a bug in the case of the logging messages, which are used for internal purposes and should be in a single language. I'll file an issue about this.

Comment: This has been fixed in trunk (we think). If you get a chance, please check it, and if the problem persists, please report [here](https://code.google.com/p/web2py/issues/detail?id=1578).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bug report has been filed and this will likely be fixed soon. In the meantime, you can simply go into the translation files and remove the translations of the Auth event logging messages (at least most of the translation files that ship with web2py do not include translations of these messages, so most likely you created your own translations at some point) -- if no translation is found, it will just use the default English message. In fact, even once a fix is in place, it would probably make sense not to have the translated messages in your files.